# Наследование форм в Delphi с возможностью работать с родительскими компонентами на дочерней форме?

Tags: delphi, ооп

Имеется базовая диалоговая форма с компонентами: кнопка "Сохранить" и "Закрыть". От этой формы я хочу создать несколько дочерних форм. Как это можно реализовать без визуального наследования, чтобы было удобно работать с родительскими компонентами на дочерней форме? Что вы делаете в этом случае?

Comment: конкретизируйте, что за работа предполагается с родительскими элементами и какими именно? этими кнопками что ли? может там вам не формы наследовать а разные фреймы на базовую форму вставлять, передавая класс фрейма в конструктор формы как параметр при создании

Comment: @teran, работа предпологается с кнопками на дочерней форме, чтобы в дальнейшем была возможность легко изменять визуальную часть кнопок и функционал. С формой и фреймом могут возникнуть трудности, когда надо, например, при определенном фрейме иметь новую кнопку на форме

Comment: "Что вы делаете в этом случае?" - использую визуальное наследование.

Comment: так мб наоборот надо иметь несколько форм, и ставить на них различные фреймы с кнопками? Начнете с базового фрейма с 2 кнопками, при неоходимости добавите с   тремя и измените на форме.